# RestTemplate получить лист городов

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

Как я могу получить list из полученного Json?

**Получаю строку из json**

```
        String line = restTemplate.postForObject(URL, root ,String.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Cities cities = om.readValue(line, Cities.class);
```

**Класс, обьект которого я хочу получить**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Cities {
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private List<String> citiesList;

    public List<String> getCitiesList() {
        return citiesList;
    }

    public void setCitiesList(List<String> citiesList) {
        this.citiesList = citiesList;
    }
}
```

При всех попытках получал null

Вывод строки line:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [{
    "TotalCount": 1,
    "Addresses": [{
      "Present": "\u0441. \u0424\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0430, \u041b\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0440-\u043d, \u041e\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0430 \u043e\u0431\u043b.",
      "Warehouses": 4,
      "MainDescription": "\u0424\u043e\u043d\u0442\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0430",
      "Area": "\u041e\u0434\u0435\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0430",
      "Region": "\u041b\u0438\u043c\u0430\u043d\u0441\u044c\u043a\u0438\u0439",
      "SettlementTypeCode": "\u0441.",
      "Ref": "0ddaf157-4b3a-11e4-ab6d-005056801329",
      "DeliveryCity": "e57694f2-14cb-11e5-add9-005056887b8d",
      "AddressDeliveryAllowed": true,
      "StreetsAvailability": false,
      "ParentRegionTypes": "\u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",
      "ParentRegionCode": "\u043e\u0431\u043b.",
      "RegionTypes": "\u0440\u0430\u0439\u043e\u043d",
      "RegionTypesCode": "\u0440-\u043d"
    }]
  }],
  "errors": [],
  "warnings": [],
  "info": [],
  "messageCodes": [],
  "errorCodes": [],
  "warningCodes": [],
  "infoCodes": []
}
```

Comment: а как джейсон выглядит? можете добавит результат вывода в консоль переменой String line?

Comment: вывод добавил, получаю около сотни таких строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина по которой Вы получаете null в том что пытаетесь распарсить массив строк с названием "Description", текущий код работал бы только в случае если JSON был примерно таким:

```
{
  "Description": ["string1","string2"]
}
```

Для лучшего понимания советую прочитать про типы данных в JSON. Про вложенность в JSON. Вам нужно например понимать разницу между массивом строк и массивом объектов, а также как выглядят простые поля из строк или поля с целочисленными значениями. А также значения аннотаций вроде @JsonProperty.

Для того чтобы решить задачу, я советую использовать сервисы, которые автоматически конвертируют JSON в объекты Java грубо говоря. Например http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.
Предпочтительно использовать такие конверторы, но нужно понимать как устроены сгенерированные классы.

Последовательность работы на этом сервисе такая:

1. Вставляете свой JSON в поле
2. Заполняете Package, Class name например называете "Response"
3. Выбираете нужные настройки, Source type - JSON, Annotation style -
   Jackson 2.x
4. Снизу нажимаете на Zip и скачиваете готовые Java классы
5. Добавляете в свой проект

Далее в Вашем случае вместо кода

```
Cities cities = om.readValue(line, Cities.class);
```

теперь указываете сгенерированный класс

```
Response response = om.readValue(line, Response.class);
```

Далее из объекта response уже можете вытаскивать данные, которые нужны для работы.

Comment: огромное спасибо